# What is the ideal way to scale font size in App Development?

Tags: android, flutter

I know this question might sound a bit odd. I am a newbie in Flutter Development. While making my app responsive I always face an issue while scaling the text. If I keep the font size constant (say 10 or 20) it sometimes looks too small on devices with large resolution or too big on small phones. Then I tried scaling it with respect to screen dimensions (like 4% or screen width etc) but then the question remains to scale it with respect to screen height or width ? Hence I want to know what is the ideal way for scaling the text in general.

Thankyou in advance for answering.

Comment: https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: should be closed because opinion based

Answer (score 2):

You can create dimension files and the sizes defined in these files will be used according to the device's dpi.
You will have to create:

1. res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml
2. res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml
3. res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml
4. res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml
5. res/values-xxxhdpi/dimens.xml

Following are the ratios you would want to use for different screen size:
3:4:6:8:12 (m:h:xh:xxh:xxxh)

Let's say you have a device(hdpi), you want to set the text size to 12sp.
So you will set text sizes as:

1. mdpi - 9sp
2. hdpi - 12sp
3. xhdpi - 18sp
4. xxhdpi - 24sp
5. xxxhdpi - 36sp

Make sure the name should be same in all 'dimens.xml'

**res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="title">12sp</dimen>
   <dimen name="paragraph">9sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="title">16sp</dimen>
   <dimen name="paragraph">12sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="title">24sp</dimen>
   <dimen name="paragraph">18sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="title">32sp</dimen>
   <dimen name="paragraph">24sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**res/values-xxxhdpi/dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="title">48sp</dimen>
   <dimen name="paragraph">36sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: in flutter? what do you want to do with those files?